# calculating cross-correlation function in xarray

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have a dataset res_1 with

```
Dimensions:    (space: 726, time: 579)
Coordinates:
  * space      (space) MultiIndex
  - latitude   (space) float64 -90.0 -82.5 -82.5 -82.5 -82.5 -82.5 -82.5 ...
  - longitude  (space) float64 0.0 0.0 60.0 120.0 180.0 240.0 300.0 0.0 30.0 ...
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-06-01 1980-06-02 1980-06-03 ...
  Data variables:
       mx2t       (time, space) float64 -1.768 -0.6035 -1.286 -1.291 1.144 ...
       dayofyear  (time) int64 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 ...
```

the space variable contains latitude and longitude pairs. I  to calculate the cross-correlation function

```
cij = (avg(mx2t(t-tau , i) * mx2t(t , j)) - avg(mx2t(t-tau , i))*avg(mx2t(t , j)))/(std(mx2t(t-tau , i))*std(mx2t , j) )
```

where avg is the expectation value and std is the standard deviation, i and j are go over all the elements in the space co-ordinate and tau goes from 0 to 200. for this I have defined a function

```
def c_out(i) :
    c1=[]
    c = np.empty(726)
    c.fill(-2.0)
    c[i]=0.0
    for j in list(range(726)):
        if i != j :
            rdi = res_1.sel(space = coord[i]).to_dataframe()
            rdj = res_1.sel(space = coord[j]).to_dataframe()
            rdi['tj'] = rdj['t']
            for tau in list(range(200)):
                rdi['mx2t_stau'] = rdi['t'].shift(tau)
                rdf = rdi.dropna()
                rdf1 = rdf.loc[pd.date_range('1982-01-01' , '1982-12-31')]
                ctemp = ((rdf1['tj']*rdf1['mx2t_stau']).mean() - rdf1['tj'].mean() * rdf1['mx2t_stau'].mean()/(rdf1['tj'].std()*rdf1['mx2t_stau'].std())
                if ctemp > c[j] :
                     c[j] = ctemp
    return c
```

and I use joblib to calculate it in parallel using

```
cij = Parallel(n_jobs=28 )(delayed(c_out)(i)for i in list(range(726))
```

I would like to know if there is a simple or(/and) more efficient way of doing the same calculations in xarray?

Comment: What do you mean better way to do this? In terms of computational performance or algorithmic implementation? Try revising your question to be more specific about what you need help with.