# With xarray, how to parallelize 1D operations on a multidimensional Dataset?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have a 4D xarray Dataset. I want to carry out a linear regression between two variables on a specific dimension (here time), and keep the regression parameters in a 3D array (the remaining dimensions).
I managed to get the results I want by using this serial code, but it is rather slow:

```
# add empty arrays to store results of the regression
res_shape = tuple(v for k,v in ds[x].sizes.items() if k != 'year')
res_dims = tuple(k for k,v in ds[x].sizes.items() if k != 'year')
ds[sl] = (res_dims, np.empty(res_shape, dtype='float32'))
ds[inter] = (res_dims, np.empty(res_shape, dtype='float32'))
# Iterate in kept dimensions
for lat in ds.coords['latitude']:
    for lon in ds.coords['longitude']:
        for duration in ds.coords['duration']:
            locator = {'longitude':lon, 'latitude':lat, 'duration':duration}
            sel = ds.loc[locator]
            res = scipy.stats.linregress(sel[x], sel[y])
            ds[sl].loc[locator] = res.slope
            ds[inter].loc[locator] = res.intercept
```

How could I speed-up and parallelize this operation?

I understand that `apply_ufunc` might be an option (and could be parallelized with dask), but I did not managed to get the parameters right.

The following questions are related but without an answer:

- [Applying numpy.polyfit to xarray Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960903/applying-numpy-polyfit-to-xarray-dataset)
- [Python: How to find regression equation of multiple 3D
  (lat-lon-time-value) dataArrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863969/python-how-to-find-regression-equation-of-multiple-3d-lat-lon-time-value-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [calculating cross-correlation function in xarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566703/calculating-cross-correlation-function-in-xarray)

**Edit 2: move previous edit to an answer**

Comment: Aren't latitude and longitude meant to be considered together?  Give two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), why do you iterate over (x1,y1), (x1,y2), (x2,y1), (x2,y2)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Two points could be at the same latitude, with different longitudes.

Comment: Yes.  Shouldn't you iterate over (x,y) pairs, rather than the cartesian product of all x's with all y's?

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer by [LCT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9974926/lct) covers most of what should be said here, **however** I think it is possible to incorporate `dask='parallelized'` with multiple outputs like you get from `scipy.stats.linregress`.

The trick here is to stack the multiple outputs into one array and then output that, you'll also have to use the `output_core_dims` kwarg to specify that the DataArray output from the `apply_ufunc()` call will have an extra dimension now:

```
def new_linregress(x, y):
    # Wrapper around scipy linregress to use in apply_ufunc
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
    return np.array([slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err])
```

```
# return a new DataArray
stats = xr.apply_ufunc(new_linregress, ds[x], ds[y],
                       input_core_dims=[['year'], ['year']],
                       output_core_dims=[["parameter"]],
                       vectorize=True,
                       dask="parallelized",
                       output_dtypes=['float64'],
                       output_sizes={"parameter": 5},
                      )
```

**N.B.** This approach currently only works with `dask='parallelized'` if you have `dask<2.0`, but it seems to work fine for multiple outputs if you have something else like `dask='allowed'`. Have a look at this [Github issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3574) for more detail.

Hope it helps!

**Edit:** I've been informed that the `dask<2.0` issue has been rectified as long as you have `xarray>=0.15.0` ! So can use `dask='parallelized'` now to speed things up. :)

Comment: This answer is awesome! Was trying to do a similar linear regression problem along a time dimension and racking my head looking at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.15.1/examples/apply_ufunc_vectorize_1d.html. The trick with putting everything into a numpy array to avoid the "NotImplementedError" is excellent, just need to split them out after :D

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to apply `scipy.stats.linregress` (and other non-ufuncs) to the xarray Dataset using `apply_ufunc()` by passing `vectorize=True` like so:

```
# return a tuple of DataArrays
res = xr.apply_ufunc(scipy.stats.linregress, ds[x], ds[y],
        input_core_dims=[['year'], ['year']],
        output_core_dims=[[], [], [], [], []],
        vectorize=True)
# add the data to the existing dataset
for arr_name, arr in zip(array_names, res):
    ds[arr_name] = arr
```

Although still serial, `apply_ufunc` is around 36x faster than the loop implementation in this specific case.

However the parallelization with dask is still not implemented with multiple output like the one from `scipy.stats.linregress`:

> NotImplementedError: multiple outputs from apply_ufunc not yet supported with dask='parallelized'

Comment: I am trying this with sp.stats.ranksums but with no luck. I am getting a ValueError about the dimension that I fix (your 'year' which actually is 'year' for me too) because the two datasets have different values of years.