# With xarray, how to perform regression on multiple dataarrays by parallelizing 1D operations?

Tags: python, regression, dask, python-xarray

I'm struggling to find a solution to the following problem.
I have 3 different xarray dataarrays (ds_pr_cru; ds_tas_cru; ds_nep), each one containing a variable. I want to perform a liear ridge regression between the three variables on a specific dimension (time), having the first two xarrays as independent variables (X1 and X2) and the third one as dependent variable (Y). Now, I've seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094320/with-xarray-how-to-parallelize-1d-operations-on-a-multidimensional-dataset/60524715#60524715) that it is possible to use xr.apply_ufunc: indeed this works if I perform both ols and ridge regression, BUT having only X1 and Y, as below.

However, I cannot find the way to implement a second predictor in the regression (but of course I need more than two, eventually). Probably I overlooked or I'm structuring the analysis in the wrong way, but it feels strange that nobody have asked how to perform a multilinear regression like this. I can only find question involving multidimensional datasets, rather than how to use multiple datasets for regressing xarrays.

I tried the following, that works:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

def new_regress(x, y):
    # Wrapper around scipy Ridge to use in apply_ufunc
    ridge = linear_model.Ridge()
    model = ridge.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1),y.reshape(-1, 1))
    slope = model.coef_
    return slope

# return a new DataArray
test = xr.apply_ufunc(new_regress,
                       ds_pr_cru.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),   # spatial subset to speed-up example
                       ds_nep.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),      # spatial subset to speed-up example
                       input_core_dims=[['time'], ['time']],
                       output_core_dims=[["parameter"]],
                       vectorize=True,
                       dask="parallelized",
                       output_dtypes=['float64'],
                       output_sizes={"parameter": 5},
                      )
print(test)

<xarray.DataArray (lat: 20, lon: 20, parameter: 1)>
array([[[24063.30273438],
        [22831.70703125],
        [20362.62695312],
        [12655.3125    ],
        [ 7683.64453125],
        [ 9202.81933594],
        [ 8463.17675781],
        [ 9290.00878906],
        [ 8692.11425781],
        [10670.50390625],
        [11069.19238281],
        [10303.24902344],
        [ 8438.82324219],
        [ 8534.91503906],
        [ 7817.84326172],
        [ 7811.36621094],
        [ 8132.60595703],
        [ 7732.609375  ],
        [ 8964.26367188],
        [ 8884.00488281]],
...
       [[ 3666.24145508],
        [ 4158.28515625],
        [ 4083.93017578],
...
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -59.75 -59.25 -58.75 -58.25 ... -51.25 -50.75 -50.25
  * lat      (lat) float64 -19.75 -19.25 -18.75 -18.25 ... -11.25 -10.75 -10.25
Dimensions without coordinates: parameter
```

If I try to similarly implement a multilinear regression:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def new_ridgereg(x1, x2, y):
    # Wrapper around scipy linregress to use in apply_ufunc
    ridge = linear_model.Ridge()
    model = ridge.fit(x1.reshape(-1, 1),x2.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1))
    r2 = ridge.score(x1,x2,y)
    ypred = ridge.predict(x1,x2)
    coef = model.coef_
    pval = stats.coef_pval(model,x1,x2,y)
    return np.array([coef, pval, r2, ypred])

# return a new DataArray
test = xr.apply_ufunc(new_ridgereg, 
                       ds_pr_cru.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)), 
                       ds_tas_cru.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),
                       ds_nep.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),
                       input_core_dims=[['time'], ['time'],['time']],
                       output_core_dims=[["parameter"]],
                       vectorize=True,
                       dask="parallelized",
                       output_dtypes=['float64'],
                       output_sizes={"parameter": 4},
                      )

test
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
g:\Shared drives\FLUXNET - FLUXCOM Unive\Code\TWS_semiarid.ipynb Cell 34 in 1
     11     return np.array([coef, pval, r2, ypred])
     13 # return a new DataArray
---> 14 test = xr.apply_ufunc(new_ridgereg, 
     15                        ds_pr_cru.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)), 
     16                        ds_tas_cru.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),
     17                        ds_nep.sel(lon = slice(-60,-50), lat = slice(-20,-10)),
     18                        input_core_dims=[['time'], ['time'],['time']],
     19                        output_core_dims=[["parameter"]],
     20                        vectorize=True,
     21                        dask="parallelized",
     22                        output_dtypes=['float64'],
     23                        output_sizes={"parameter": 4},
     24                       )

File c:\Users\mastr\miniconda3\envs\geo_clim\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\computation.py:1204, in apply_ufunc(func, input_core_dims, output_core_dims, exclude_dims, vectorize, join, dataset_join, dataset_fill_value, keep_attrs, kwargs, dask, output_dtypes, output_sizes, meta, dask_gufunc_kwargs, *args)
   1202 # feed DataArray apply_variable_ufunc through apply_dataarray_vfunc
   1203 elif any(isinstance(a, DataArray) for a in args):
-> 1204     return apply_dataarray_vfunc(
   1205         variables_vfunc,
   1206         *args,
   1207         signature=signature,
   1208         join=join,
...
   1735             sample_weight.shape, (n_samples,)
   1736         )
   1737     )

ValueError: Sample weights must be 1D array or scalar
```

Thanks